# SVN E155016 The working copy database at ... is corrupt

Tags: database, svn, corrupt

My computer exploded while in the middle of an svn (version 1.8.8) update command. Now svn does nothing just tells me the working copy is corrupt.

svn: E155016 The working copy database at [dir] is corrupt

I have no idea what to do, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue with a cleanup + revert + update (in that order)

Answer (score 1):

**Cleanup**

Try `svn cleanup` in your working copy

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.cleanup.html

**New  checkout**

Try to make a new checkout to different place. If new checkout works properly, delete the corrupted one and replace it with new checkout.

Comment: Doesn't do anything, just gives the same error. In fact every command I have tried gives the same error.

Comment: cleanup, commit, revert, status, update all just give the error: the working copy database is corrupt

Comment: When do the new checkout to separated path

Answer (score 0):

When I removed the complete folder, repeated the checkout I got the same error....
So it seems consistent!

However,I was checking out into .  (currentDir)

When I then checkout out into another directory it worked fine!?!?!
So much for transparent misbehaviours.....

**Environment**

- DISK:   NTFS disk mounted into a ubuntu 18.04 guest
- CLIENT: svn, version 1.9.7 (r1800392)
- SERVER: version 1.7.10 (r1485443)