# NFS exported SVN repo appears corrupt to client

Tags: svn, freebsd, nfs

On FreeBSD 12.0-STABLE r345345, when I export an SVN repo over NFS, I have the same symptom as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192155/svn-e155016-the-working-copy-database-at-is-corrupt):

`svn: E155016: The working copy database at '/usr/src' is corrupt.`

The SVN repo appears fine:

```
$ svnlite info /usr/src-12.0
Path: /usr/src-12.0
Working Copy Root Path: /usr/src-12.0
URL: svn://svn.example.com/base/stable/12
Relative URL: ^/stable/12
Repository Root: svn://svn.example.com/base
Repository UUID: ccf9f872-aa2e-dd11-9fc8-001c23d0bc1f
Revision: 341836
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: zeising
Last Changed Rev: 341831
Last Changed Date: 2018-12-11 13:01:38 -0800 (Tue, 11 Dec 2018)
```

And I'm exporting it fairly typical fashion, but correct me if I'm wrong:

```
$ cat /etc/exports
/usr/src-12.0 -ro -maproot=root -network 127.0.0.0/8
/usr/obj-12.0 -ro -maproot=root -network 127.0.0.0/8
$ showmount -e
Exports list on localhost:
/usr/src-12.0                      127.0.0.0
/usr/obj-12.0                      127.0.0.0
```

I found this problem originally between two different hosts, but discovered that a localhost export and mount was sufficient to reproduce the problem.

If I mount that NFS share and inspect the NFS-mounted copy of the repo, `svnlite` reports that it is corrupt:

```
# mount localhost:/usr/src-12.0 /mnt
# svnlite info /mnt
svn: E155016: The working copy database at '/mnt' is corrupt.
```

Copying the repo via `rsync` or nullfs mounting the repo to the client works fine.

I've verified all the files and directories in the tree by doing a sha256 verification with `mtree(8)`:

```
# mtree -K sha256 -cp /usr/src-12.0 > mtree.out
# mount localhost:/usr/src-12.0 /mnt
# mtree -p /mnt < mtree.out
.:      flags ("uarch" is not "none")
# echo $?
2
```

The only difference that mtree finds is that the /mnt directory doesn't have the `uarch` flag set:

```
# ls -lod /mnt /usr/src-12.0
drwxr-xr-x  25 root  wheel  -     40 Apr 12 14:53 /mnt/
drwxr-xr-x  25 root  wheel  uarch 40 Apr 12 14:53 /usr/src-12.0/
```

So it appears that the NFS export itself is creating some sort of breakage with SVN.  How can I find and fix the problem?

**Edit:** After adding:

```
rpc_lockd_enable="YES"
rpc_statd_enable="YES"
```

to the server's `/etc/rc.conf` and rebooting the server, sockstat shows:

```
# sockstat | grep rpc
root     rpc.lockd  1051  3  dgram  -> /var/run/logpriv
root     rpc.statd  1043  4  udp6   *:611                 *:*
root     rpc.statd  1043  5  tcp6   *:611                 *:*
root     rpc.statd  1043  6  udp4   *:611                 *:*
root     rpc.statd  1043  7  tcp4   *:611                 *:*
root     rpc.statd  1043  9  dgram  -> /var/run/logpriv
root     rpcbind    1019  5  stream /var/run/rpcbind.sock
root     rpcbind    1019  6  udp6   *:111                 *:*
root     rpcbind    1019  7  udp6   *:901                 *:*
root     rpcbind    1019  8  tcp6   *:111                 *:*
root     rpcbind    1019  9  udp4   *:111                 *:*
root     rpcbind    1019  10 udp4   *:681                 *:*
root     rpcbind    1019  11 tcp4   *:111                 *:*
root     rpcbind    1019  13 udp6   *:*                   *:*
```

Yet the client still complains:

```
# umount /mnt
# mount localhost:/usr/src-12.0 /mnt
# svnlite info /mnt
svn: E155016: The working copy database at '/mnt' is corrupt.
```

Comment: You probably need `rpc_lockd_enable="YES"` and `rpc_statd_enable="YES"`.

Comment: Thank you, @arrowd, but sadly, no joy.  Edited.

Comment: Do not use Subversion over NFS, it is discouraged and performs badly.